# Add click event to the summary row of grid in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs2

Asked this question yesterday but not getting any response to posting it again in diffrent words-

I have two columns with summary row-

```
var cols = [
      { id: 'myCol1', header: 'Price1', dataIndex: 'PRICE1', type: 'float', width: 50, summaryType: 'sum' },
      { id: 'myCol2', header: 'Price2', dataIndex: 'PRICE2', type: 'float', width: 50, summaryType: 'sum' },
];
```

I want to add cellclick event to these summary row so that on click I can open a new window
If I use cellclick event of grid, it works for all cells except this summary row.

Is there any other event which I can use so that I would be able to click on it.

**UPDATE:**

I have used following listener which is not working for summary row

```
listeners: {
  cellclick: function(grid, rowIndex, cellIndex) {
    // do whatever
  },
  scope: this
}
```

Comment: wat have u tried and share some code regarding that to help u..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no built-in event for summary row click. What you can do is add a listener to the cell element itself.

You can do that easily by using the [`delegate`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-addListener) option of the listener. But this option is only available for DOM elements events, so we also have to use the [`element`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-cfg-listeners) option to hook our event on the grid's body element (alternatively, you can use something like `myGrid.getEl().on({ ... })`).

Here's an example of listeners that you would add directly to your grid's config:

```
listeners: {
    scope: this
    ,click: {
        element: 'body'
        // Would have been great to use '.x-grid-row-summary .x-grid-cell',
        // but delegate only accept a *simple selector* which, seemingly,
        // means just one class...
        ,delegate: '.x-grid-cell'
        ,fn: function(e, target) {
            // Remove the condition if you want to catch all cells. You won't
            // have all the arguments that are available in the cellclick
            // event, though.
            if (Ext.fly(target).up('tr').is('.x-grid-row-summary')) {
                // The cellIndex is assigned by the table view when it render the
                // cell element.
                alert('Click on summary cell at index ' + target.cellIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this kind of code relies on class names and the `cellIndex` property that are set by Ext, and that may change in the future... Keep that in mind when you upgrade the lib!

Comment: Like in Ext 2.3.0?? That's very probable that this code won't work with this version... I've tested it against 4.2.0. You should explicit the version in the question or tag. You can try with `Ext.get` instead of `fly `, but I fear that won't be enough; the markup and/or listener options may have changed as well.

Comment: I came up with this- `if (Ext.fly(e.target).up('tr').is('.x-grid-row-summary'))` But this is always false even if I click on summary row.

Comment: I can't find the docs for the summary in 2.3, but I guess the CSS classes would rather be 'x-grid3-summary-row' and 'x-grid3-cell'.

Comment: What extension/plugin are you using for the summary? If you can setup a working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com), I think I'll be able to work out a solution.

Comment: I have removed the condition `if (Ext.fly(target).up('tr').is('.x-grid-row-summary'))` so that it will catch all the cells. But now I am unable to get rowIndex, colIndex and the clicked row data. `target.cellIndex` or `e.target.cellIndex` does not work in 2.3.0

Comment: You should be able to get the cell index with the view's `getCellIndex` method, and the row with `findRowIndex`. You can find these methods in the [code of the view class](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/2.3.0/source/GridView.html#Ext-grid-GridView). From what I see, it should work if you pass `e.target` to them. Once you've got the row index, you can get the record with `grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the code u have used adding event for row click, but still i am adding this code to grid panel hope it helps,sry if u have tried already.. I have edited this below will do i believe..

```
   listeners: {
      cellclick: function(iView, iCellEl, iColIdx, iRecord, iRowEl, iRowIdx, iEvent) {

            var fieldName = iView.getGridColumns()[iColIdx].dataIndex;
console.log(fieldName );
}
    }
```

Comment: sry did't see that k hv u went to docs..just check this out wil help ...http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.selection.CellModel-event-select